# c# Any sample code to POST xml payload using Webview2?

Tags: c#, xml, post, webview2

I'm using winform with Webview2 and trying to access a website using POST xml payload. I am very new to Webview2 and can't seem to go anywhere with it. I can browse through Webview2 like normal, but cannot seem to find a way to post the xml payload.  Any samples would be greatly appreciated!! I have tried the following, but no luck.

```
        using (var stream = CreateStream(data))
        {
            webView21.CoreWebView2.AddWebResourceRequestedFilter("*", CoreWebView2WebResourceContext.All);

            CoreWebView2WebResourceRequest webResourceRequest = webView21.CoreWebView2.Environment.CreateWebResourceRequest(uri, "POST", stream, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            webView21.CoreWebView2.NavigateWithWebResourceRequest(webResourceRequest);
        }
    }
    public static Stream CreateStream(string s)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(s);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        return stream;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `using` statement and your code will work (also the AddWebResourceRequestedFilter is unnecessary). The `CoreWebView2.Navigate*` methods start a navigation but it is not complete until the various navigation events are raised. Your stream is required for the navigation which will continue on after the `NavigateWithWebResourceRequest` method completes.

```
        var stream = CreateStream(data);

        CoreWebView2WebResourceRequest webResourceRequest = webView21.CoreWebView2.Environment.CreateWebResourceRequest(uri, "POST", stream, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        webView21.CoreWebView2.NavigateWithWebResourceRequest(webResourceRequest);
    }
    public static Stream CreateStream(string s)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(s);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        return stream;
    }
```

WebView2 should be done with the stream once the CoreWebView2.ContentLoading event has been raised at which point the stream can be disposed.

Comment: I'm surprised, that the stream can't be disposed. A memorystream does not need to, but other stream types do.

Comment: WebView2 should be done with the stream once ContentLoading is raised. I'll update the answer with that.